# How to launch julia webserver?

Tags: web-services, julia

As I know, in older Julia installation there was a bat file that launch Julia-lang web-server on windows, where is it gone? and how can I achieve the same functionality in newer versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older Julia web server launcher that was shipped as a `bat` file in Julia package now is gone and it't functionality is transferred to [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) package.